# How to change the EC2 instance types in a Elastic Beanstalk environment programmatically?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3

I want to use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.update_environment) to change the EC2 instance types in an Elastic Beanstalk environment.

However, I can't find the correct function to do that.

[`update_environment`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.update_environment) doesn't seem to provide the ability to change EC2 instance type.

All the `update_*` functions don't seem to provide this functionality.

My `Environment type` is `Load balanced`, and I use `Combine purchase options and instances` for  `Fleet composition`.

Anyone knows how to change the instance types used by elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [update_environment](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.update_environment) to update instance type.

**Verified** example (i.e. I used it on my own EB env):

```
import boto3

eb = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk')

response = eb.update_environment(
    ApplicationName='<your-eb-app-name>',
    EnvironmentName='<your-eb-env-name>',
    OptionSettings=[
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
            'OptionName': 'InstanceType',
            'Value': 't2.small'
        },
    ]
)

print(response)
```

#### Update for spot

The spot settings for EB env are set using [aws:ec2:instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-ec2instances).

```
response = eb.update_environment(
    ApplicationName='<your-eb-app-name>',
    EnvironmentName='<your-eb-env-name>',
    OptionSettings=[
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:ec2:instances',
            'OptionName': 'EnableSpot',
            'Value': 'true'
        },
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:ec2:instances',
            'OptionName': 'InstanceTypes',
            'Value': 't2.large,t3.large'
        }      
    ]
)
```

There are more options to be set, which depend on your exact requirements.

Comment: My `InstanceTypes` was originally `t2a.medium, t3a.medium`. After applying your `OptionSettings` with `Value` equal to `t2.large, t3.large`, it changes to `t2.large, t3a.large, t3a.medium`. This is so strange.

Comment: I get the configuration file using `eb config get <my_configuration_name>`.

Comment: I don't want to use `*.medium` instance types.

Comment: I have to specify at least 2 instance types because I use spot instances.

Comment: @Brian Hi. I updated the answer with spot specific settings. Your question did not mention spot, thus at first I included most commonly used setting for instance type only.

Comment: @Brian It should be `InstanceTypes`, not `InstanceType`. Could  you please double check your code?